# Are Consumable in-app purchases supported by RequestProductPurchaseAsync?

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8

I'm adding in-app purchase support in my app. It says that there are two types of in-app products: durable and consumable. It's ok.

But here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh967814.aspx we can read:
**ProductType** attribute for ProductReceipt element: Determines the product type. **Currently only supports a value of Durable.**

Can anybody explain what does it mean? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in "Receipts" section, it says type can be Durable or Consumable.

Comment: This is not an answer. I know that there are two supported product types. I know that it works. But I am confused by specified quote provided by specified link. It looks like some kind of error or outdated information is presented in documentation. But I don't want to beleive in it. I beleive that correct explanation exists.

Comment: I suppose so, documentation in your link is missing some more details about the link i provided..May be you send this feedback to MS. At the bottom of the page, there is survey type question - where you can send this details.